# How to print vertically from bottom?

Tags: python, oop

how do i get the letters to print from bottom up?
input = 'mary is happy'

```
current output : 
m  i  h
a  s  a
r     p
y     p
      y

desired output:
       h
 m     a
 a     p
 r  i  p
 y  s  y
```

Comment: You can only print line by line, but what you can do is pad each word to match the length of the biggest word such that you get the desired output. See answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
user_input = "Mary is happy"

words = user_input.split(" ")      # ["Mary", "is", "happy"]
biggest = max(words, key=len)      # get the biggest word

# pad each word to match the size of the biggest word
# --> words = [" Mary", "   is", "happy"]
words = [word.rjust(len(biggest)) for word in words]

for c in zip(*words):
    # c is a tuple of the i-th character for every word
    print(*c)
```